# Show chart in dialog box when a button is pressed

Tags: sapui5

My Goal is to launch a popup or dialog or messagebox whatever pops up and is able to contain the graph. 
Dialog is working but chart data is not coming in sapui5

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

Using `SAPUI5`'s `JSView` to create the dialog and Radial Chart, triggered by button press event, you can have a look at the full application here [SAPUI5 Dialog](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/5KmYHa/#/masterList/0)

```js
openDialog: function() {
  if (!this.draggableDialog) {
    this.draggableDialog = new Dialog({
      title: "Charts",
      type: "Message",
      contentWidth: "900px",
      contentHeight: "700px",
      resizable: true,
      content: [
        new RadialMicroChart({
          percentage: 75,
          total: 100,
          size: "Responsive",
          valueColor: "Critical"
        })
      ],

      beginButton: new Button({
        text: "Close",
        press: function() {
          this.draggableDialog.close();
        }.bind(this)
      })
    });
    this.getView().addDependent(this.draggableDialog);
  }
  this.draggableDialog.open();

}
```