# Add items to SelectDialog dynamically

Tags: sapui5

I need to add more items to the `SelectDialog` control based on the Odata from the backend based on a condition. The code is,

```
 if (!this._oDialog) {
this._oDialog = new sap.m.SelectDialog({});
this._oDialog.setModel(oParentModel);
this._oDialog.bindAggregation("items", {
                            path: "/et_getSidSet",
                            template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                                                        title: "{Sid}"
                                                    })
                                                });


if (v === '1') {
var oItem1 = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title: 'PC2',
            type: 'Active'
 });

 this._oDialog.addItem(oItem1);
} else if (v === '2') {
var oItem1 = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title: 'AC2',
            type: 'Active'
});

this._oDialog.addItem(oItem1);
var oItem2 = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
          title: 'IC2',
          type: 'Active'
   });

this._oDialog.addItem(oItem2);
}}
```

The issue is, when I click on helprequest icon, the item is not adding for the very first time. However, its added from second time onwards.
I need the item to get added for the first time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code of how the function to add the new item is called? I see the If conditions to add new items, but I cannot figure out how it is called.

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question, displaying charts in a dialog https://stackoverflow.com/a/53304495/7626277

Answer (score 0):

Using `SAPUI5`'s `JSView` to create the dialog and Radial Chart, triggered by button press event, you can have a look at the full application here [Plunkr Example](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/5KmYHa/#/masterList/0)

```js
openDialog: function() {
  if (!this.draggableDialog) {
    this.draggableDialog = new Dialog({
      title: "Charts",
      type: "Message",
      contentWidth: "900px",
      contentHeight: "700px",
      resizable: true,
      content: [
        new RadialMicroChart({
          percentage: 75,
          total: 100,
          size: "Responsive",
          valueColor: "Critical"
        })
      ],

      beginButton: new Button({
        text: "Close",
        press: function() {
          this.draggableDialog.close();
        }.bind(this)
      })
    });
    this.getView().addDependent(this.draggableDialog);
  }
  this.draggableDialog.open();

}
```